# Meteor - Create a webhook

Tags: meteor, kadira

I'd like to implement a webhook with Meteor

I'm using the [kadira/flowrouter](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router) Meteor plugin but no way to get POST data. Neither queryParams or params return the body of the message that I want to get.

```
FlowRouter.route('/my_weebhook', {
    action: function(params, queryParams) {
        console.log(queryParams);
        console.log(params);
    }
});
```

Comment: Routing internally in your Meteor app will not give you any http data. If you want to get the post data from a Webservice call please add the code.here on how you call the service.

Comment: I just put this code in lib/router.js
The route works

Comment: Ok, so what do you actually want to do with that POST data body?

Comment: I'd like to transform and save in Mongodb data sent in the POST body. I want to build a webhook which will be called by a Telegram Messenger Bot: 
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates

Answer (score 3):

I do not know how to use  kadira/flowrouter but you can use Meteor base package [WebApp](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html)

to achieve what you need. Below is a sample code. You need to code or import something like this in your server.js

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';
import url from "url";


WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/my_webhook', (req, res) => {    

  //Below two lines show how you can parse the query string from url if you need to
  const urlParts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  const someVar = urlParts.query.someVar;
  
  //Below code shows how to get the request body if you need
  let body = "";
  req.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (data) {
    body += data;
  }));

  req.on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
 //You can access complete request body data in the variable body here.
 console.log("body : ", body);
 //write code to save body in db or do whatever you want to do with body.
  }));
 
  //Below you send response from your webhook listener
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("OK");
  
});
```